# Trying to make a genetic algorithm

Tags: python, machine-learning, genetic-algorithm

I've been studying about Genetic Algorithms lately and I decided to make my own using Python. I'll share the working I have done, below.

### These are some helping function that I made to use in my driver function:

#### Note: These functions are fine I believe, and can be used as it is.

```
# Generates Random Population
def generate_random_population(npop, limits=list(zip(np.zeros(5),np.ones(5))), ngenes=5):
  
  def new_ind():
    return [random.uniform(limits[i][0], limits[i][1]) for i in range(ngenes)]

  return np.array([new_ind() for n in range(npop)])


# Function to evaluate all individuals and give them a score
# fopt1 only has a minimum (unimodal) at x = (0,0, ..., 0) in which fopt1 = 0.
def fopt1(ind):
  
    x0 = [ind[len(ind)-1]]
    xlast = [ind[0]]
    working_array = np.concatenate((x0,ind,xlast))
    res = 0

    for j in range(1, len(ind)+1):
        res += (2*working_array[j-1] + (working_array[j]**2)*working_array[j+1] - working_array[j+1])**2

    return res

# Receives a certain population of individuals and an evaluation function (usually called * fitness function *) and returns an ordered list of tuples
def eval_pop(pop, f):
  # Returns a list of tuples in descending order of the goodness of f. Shape of tuples are (individual, score), e.g., ([2.3,0.004,1,8.2,6], 0.361).
  
    list = []
    
    for i in pop:
        j = (pop, f(pop))
        list.append(j)
    

    return list


# Function to produce a next generation of individuals is to select the pairs that will interbreed to have offspring
def couples_selection(ordered_pop, n_elitism):
    if len(ordered_pop) < 10:
        print("Error: population's size should be higher than 9")
        return
  
    len_a = int(len(ordered_pop)/10)
    len_b = len_a * 3
    len_c = len_a * 4

    a = np.ones(len_a) * 0.5 / len_a
    b = np.ones(len_b) * 0.3 / len_b
    c = np.ones(len_c) * 0.15 / len_c
    d = np.ones(len(ordered_pop) - len_a*8)
    d = d * 0.05 / len(d)

    prob = np.concatenate((a,b,c,d))
    indices = range(len(ordered_pop))
    selected_indices = [choice(indices, 2, p=prob) for i in range(len(ordered_pop) - n_elitism)]
    couples = [[ordered_pop[i1], ordered_pop[i2]] for [i1,i2] in selected_indices]
    return np.array(couples)

def mutate(ind, limits):
    # print("Mutating individual ", ind)
    factor = 1 + (0.2 * choice([-1,1], 1))
    gene_index = choice(range(len(ind)), 1)[0]
    mutated_val = ind.item(gene_index) * factor

    if mutated_val < limits[gene_index][0]:
        mutated_val = limits[gene_index][0]
    elif mutated_val > limits[gene_index][1]:
        mutated_val = limits[gene_index][1]

    ind[gene_index] = mutated_val

    return

def crossover(couple):
    ancestor1 = couple[0]
    ancestor2 = couple[1]

    c1, c2 = ancestor1.copy(), ancestor2.copy()
    
    pt = randint(1, len(ancestor1)-2)
    # perform crossover
    c1 = ancestor1[:pt] + ancestor2[pt:]
    c2 = ancestor2[:pt] + ancestor1[pt:]

    return [c1, c2]
  

def get_offspring(couples, mutp, limits):

    children = [crossover(couple) for couple in couples]
    mutation_roulette = [choice([True, False], 1, p=[mutp, 1-mutp]) for _ in children]
    children_roulette = list(zip(children, mutation_roulette))

    for child in children_roulette:
        if child[1][0]:
            mutate(child[0], limits) 
            # print("Mutated: ",child[0])

    return np.array([child[0] for child in children_roulette])
```

#### Problem:

When I run the following driver function with the following function call:

`runGA(100, 5, list(zip(np.ones(5)*-2,np.ones(5)*2)), fopt13, 4, 0.4, 25)`

```
def runGA(npop, ngenes, limits, fitness, nelitism, mutp, ngenerations):
    pop = generate_random_population(npop, limits, ngenes)
    sorted_pop_with_score = eval_pop(pop, fitness)
    new_pop = np.array([p[0] for p in sorted_pop_with_score])

    for g in range(ngenerations):

    # TO DO: Complete your GA!
    
        couples = couples_selection(new_pop, nelitism)
        popp = get_offspring(couples,mutp, limits)
        eval_pop_result = eval_pop(pop,fitness)
    
    
    # END OF TO DO
    
        print("Winner after generation", g, ":", eval_pop_result[0])

    print("Absolute winner:")
    return sorted_pop_with_score[0]
```

I'm getting this error in the crossover function:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-375adbb7b149> in <module>
----> 1 runGA(100, 5, list(zip(np.ones(5)*-2,np.ones(5)*2)), fopt13, 4, 0.4, 25)

<ipython-input-12-6619b9c7d476> in runGA(npop, ngenes, limits, fitness, nelitism, mutp, ngenerations)
      8     # TO DO: Complete your GA!
      9         couples = couples_selection(new_pop, nelitism)
---> 10         popp = get_offspring(couples,mutp, limits)
     11         eval_pop_result = eval_pop(pop,fitness)
     12 

<ipython-input-16-5e8ace236573> in get_offspring(couples, mutp, limits)
     34 def get_offspring(couples, mutp, limits):
     35 
---> 36     children = [crossover(couple) for couple in couples]
     37     mutation_roulette = [choice([True, False], 1, p=[mutp, 1-mutp]) for _ in children]
     38     children_roulette = list(zip(children, mutation_roulette))

<ipython-input-16-5e8ace236573> in <listcomp>(.0)
     34 def get_offspring(couples, mutp, limits):
     35 
---> 36     children = [crossover(couple) for couple in couples]
     37     mutation_roulette = [choice([True, False], 1, p=[mutp, 1-mutp]) for _ in children]
     38     children_roulette = list(zip(children, mutation_roulette))

<ipython-input-16-5e8ace236573> in crossover(couple)
     25     print(len(ancestor1))
     26     print(len(ancestor2))
---> 27     c1 = ancestor1[:pt] + ancestor2[pt:]
     28     c2 = ancestor2[:pt] + ancestor1[pt:]
     29 

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (39,5) (61,5)
```

#### Note:

I also tried the np.concatenate function but it gives the following error on the same step:
`TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: So it looks like you need to run `couples_selection()` on the population for each generation, then run `get_offspring()` on the couples returned from `couples_selection()`, and then run `eval_pop()` on the population returned from `get_offspring()`. Then, the winner of that generation will be the individual from the returned list of `eval_pop()` that had the highest score. It looks like `eval_pop()` is supposed to sort its returned list in descending order of score, but doesn't appear to; otherwise, the `[0]` index of the returned list would be the one with the highest score, aka the winner.

Comment: Also, if you're returning `sorted_pop_with_score[0]` as the absolute winner, then it seems like you need to be adding the winner of each generation to some list, and then run `eval_pop()` on that list after you complete all the generations, and set `sorted_pop_with_score` to the result of that final `eval_pop()`. Does everything I've said make sense so far? It seems like you're pretty close to finishing, really there's not much left to do, basically all you have left is to put everything together that you've made so far, other than getting sorting implemented.

Comment: @RandomDavis Thank you so much for taking the time to read and answer my question. And yes, it makes sense. However, if you would be willing to help me by taking out a minute and rewrite this function in the answer section. I would be very thankful and I'll gladly accept it as a solution.

Comment: I think the info I gave you should be enough for you to attempt a solution yourself; if you get stuck then I and others could offer advice on how to proceed, but giving you the whole answer would mean I'd have to write everything as well as test it, which is just more work than I'm willing to do in addition to the analysis and explanation I've already done. If you have a specific question about implementing anything I've mentioned so far, by all means I'll try to answer it.

Comment: @RandomDavis I tried your solution and I guess it'll work, however I'm facing some issues in the crossover function. Would you mind taking a look? I re-edited my question. Much thanks!

Comment: @RandomDavis resolved the issue! Thanks. You can paste the above comment in the answer section and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comments turned into an answer:

So it looks like you need to run `couples_selection()` on the population for each generation, then run `get_offspring()` on the couples returned from `couples_selection()`, and then run `eval_pop()` on the population returned from `get_offspring()`. Then, the winner of that generation will be the individual from the returned list of `eval_pop()` that had the highest score. It looks like `eval_pop()` is supposed to sort its returned list in descending order of score, but doesn't appear to; otherwise, the `[0]` index of the returned list would be the one with the highest score, aka the winner.

Also, if you're returning `sorted_pop_with_score[0]` as the absolute winner, then it seems like you need to be adding the winner of each generation to some list, and then run `eval_pop()` on that list after you complete all the generations, and set `sorted_pop_with_score` to the result of that final `eval_pop()`.